# How to apply jQuery function upon appending a <div> via Ajax?

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I'm generating a `<div>` dynamically and I want that a jQuery function should be applied to it upon generating but it isnt working. I tried `.on` method but it doesnt work the way I want. The `<div>` to which I want to apply the function is of `claas= portlet-content and id= live_graph` whose parent `<div>` is of class `portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all'>`

Where I'm going wrong?

**The dynamicly generated `<div>'s`**

```
HTMLstr += "<div class='portlet ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all'>"+ \
        "<div class='portlet-header ui-widget-header ui-corner-all'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick'>"+\
        "</span>Live Graph</div>" + \
        "<div class='portlet-content' id='live_graph' style='height: 270px  margin: 0 auto'>" + \   
// Want to call the function when the above <div> is generated
        "</div></div>"

return HttpResponse(HTMLstr)
```

**jQuery function(Genereating Live Chart)**

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#live_graph').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

**Ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/dashboard/",
            data : { 'widgets_list' : widgets_list },
            success: function(result){
                console.log(widgets_list);
                $("#column1").append(result);     // div gets appended.
                }
            });
```

This is what I've tried:-

Instead of

```
$(function () { in the jQuery function
```

I replaced it with :-

```
$('.portlet').on('ready', '#live_graph',function() {
```

but it did not work.Where I'm going wrong?

**Question2** `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )`  Syntax for `on`

Can `ready` be an event?

**This is what I've tried**

AJAX Success function

```
success: function(result){
                console.log(widgets_list);
                $("#column1").append(result);
                $(".column").sortable("refresh");
                $("#column1").generate_live_graph();


                }
```

jQuery Function

```
function generate_live_graph(){

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        $('#live_graph').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'spline',
                animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[0];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: (function() {
                    // generate an array of random data
                    var data = [],
                        time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        i;

                    for (i = -19; i <= 0; i++) {
                        data.push({
                            x: time + i * 1000,
                            y: Math.random()
                        });
                    }
                    return data;
                })()
            }]
        });
    });

});

}
```

Comment: `on` is for delegating event handlers, not for running arbitrary functions. If you want to run a function on the new element, just run it after you call `.append()`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: yes call this high chart function after appending div in ajax success. it will work.

Comment: @Barmar- I've tried that already. But it didnt worked.

Comment: @developerCK- tried that. but didnt worked. `$("#column1").append(result);
                generate_live_graph();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for question 1-

put you highChart function code in general function and call it in after appending div in ajax success.

```
$("#column1").make_highCharts();
```

for answer of your question-2

**There is also $(document).on("ready", handler), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. This behaves similarly to the ready method but if the ready event has already fired and you try to .on("ready") the bound handler will not be executed. Ready handlers bound this way are executed after any bound by the other three methods above.**

for event in .on(events,..

plz visit:http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: By the word general function, you mean that `function abc(){$(function () { ` and then calling it after appending of div?

Comment: make a function make_highCharts() and just put code that is in inside $(document).ready(function(){ ...});

Comment: plz remove this $(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

    and closing second last line });

Comment: Same error!! `TypeError: $(...).generate_live_graph is not a function`

Comment: got it, call this generate_live_graph(); b/c it is not a plugin of jquery, it is a general function.do not call like $().generate_live_graph();

Comment: Amazed. I've tried that earlier also before posting this question, but it didnt worked that time. it works now. Bizzare. Thanks. But I have a query. Like this I've 3-4 more highcharts functions. In this I have explicitly called `generate_live_graph();` because currently I was trying to show only one graph. What if I want to show graphs other than live graphs? Wouldnt this function call(`generate_live_graph`) will then become irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

`$(function(){  });` is the same as `$(document).ready(function(){  });`, for starters, so you've got some redundancy there.

`on()` should be applied to the closest parent element that will not be replaced at any point.

You can likely simplify what you're doing to:

```
$.post({
    "/dashboard/",
    { 'widgets_list' : widgets_list },
    function(result){
        console.log(widgets_list);
        $("#column1").append(result);     // div gets appended.
        $('#live_graph').highcharts( /* ... rest of the init code */ );
    }
});
```

This assumes there is something else (say, a button) that will be used to trigger the creation of your chart. By putting the init code inside the callback function of `post()`, your code will wait until it has a response to create the chart. Calling `append` before it should ensure that the element is present and query-able by HighCharts.

You'd probably want to adjust this to add error-handling. It's also worth noting that if you're doing a simple lookup, a GET with [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) might be even easier...

Comment: Yes `$('#live_graph').highcharts`  doesnt works inside the `<div class='portlet-content' id='live_graph' style='height: 270px  margin: 0 auto'>"`

Comment: Isnt happening. I've updated my question with what I've tried. Please have a look at it